# Is there any way to deter this determined guy?

Tags: discussion, support

This guy, https://superuser.com/users/937962/adam-c, has only been on SE for 11 days, and earning of 5 points, is already start poking at my well asked question.

It is understandable, for new people to start at somewhere. However, what annoying is that, after he's been rejected,
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/785031

He's doing it again!? I just cannot believe that after merely he's been rejected for only several days, he's doing it again, making the exactly same edit, and of course, got rejected for the exact same reason as well. 
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/787399

How to deter an overzealous guy like him?

Comment: @Ramhound, that's already the third one, not the second one in my OP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not much. Just keep calm, reject edits that seem wrong and if they seem to go through, roll back.

That said, there's *some* merits to his edits you might consider - switching the title to include the version, and rather than his slash and burn approach, maybe switch from the "conversational" tone to something more formal.

In short, rather than rejecting outright, why not consider some of the better aspects of his edits, and roll them into your post?

In addition, once Lernkurve fixes his answer - your edits would be obsolete. If not, you can still pick his answer as the correct one, then post a second answer crediting his with your different approach options.